# How to define if no radio button is not checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two radio button and I want to define it if no radio button is checked set display block to an error but it. I wrote the below code but I think it is working on both of them. how can I define it that if one of them is checked is true and there is no need to run this function to both of them?
here is my snippet :

```js
$(".nexti").click(function(){
  if (!$(this).find('input[name=radio]').is(':checked')) {
  $(".alertnext").css("display","block"); 
  }
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
First <input type="radio" name="radio"  value=""  />
Second <input type="radio" name="radio"  value=""  /> 
<div class="alertnext" style="display:none;"> Error !</div>
<button type="" class="nexti">Next</button>
```

Comment: `$(this).find` ? *no!* , `radio buttons` are siblings by your `button`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont use `this` and `find()` inside the click function, just the input selector:

```js
$(".nexti").click(function(){
    if (!$('input[name=radio]').is(':checked')) {
  $(".alertnext").css("display","block"); 
    } else $(".alertnext").css("display","none"); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
First <input type="radio" name="radio"  value=""  />
Second <input type="radio" name="radio"  value=""  /> 
<div class="alertnext" style="display:none;"> Error !</div>
<button type="" class="nexti">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$(".nexti").click(function(){
  $(".alertnext").css("display","none"); 
  if (!$('input[name=radio]').is(':checked')) {
    $(".alertnext").css("display","block"); 
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".nexti").click(function(){
 if (!$('input[name=radio]').is(':checked')) {
    $(".alertnext").css("display","block"); 
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with ids

```js
$(".nexti").click(function() {
console.log()
  if (!$('#rbf').is(':checked')||$('#rbs').is(':checked')) {
    $(".alertnext").css("display", "block");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
First <input type="radio" id='rbf' name="radio" value="" />
Second <input type="radio" id='rbs' name="radio" value="" />
<div class="alertnext" style="display:none;"> Error !</div>
<button type="" class="nexti">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("document").ready(function()
{
 $("[name='rd']").change(function ()
 {
  $("#txt").html($("input[name='rd']:checked").val());
 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
First <input type="radio" name="rd"  value="first"  /><br>
Second <input type="radio" name="rd" value="second"  /> 
<div id="txt"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use this:

```
!$('input[name=radio]')
.toArray()
.every(function (val) {
   return $(val).prop('checked')
})
```

within your `if(...)` condition.

Else, you could use:

```
var error = !$('input[name=radio]')
    .toArray()
    .every(function (val) {
        return $(val).prop('checked')
    })

if(error) { //show error }
```

Basically, .every(...) checks if both of them are checked. .prop(...) is better test of `checked`. So, using both you can achieve what you need.